# How to keep looping in while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a table with five rows for example, and my `while` loop will display the five rows for me as per normal.
I‘m trying to get the loop to keep looping records until let's say `$count = 12`. I want to start the counter at `0` and it will end at `12`. So, I pretty much want the loop to keep showing the same records randomly until it shows me 12 or so results and then stops.

Comment: Would you please share a minimal code example that produces the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Simple as `while ($a != 12)`

```
$counter = 0;

while ($counter != 12) {
    // Do stuff
    $counter = rand(0, 24);
}
```